# Change position of strings separated by character using php

Tags: php, string

I have a string `18-04`, I want to make it `04-18`.
I have tried doing this :

```
$myStr = "18-04";
$first = substr($myStr, 0, 1);
$second = substr($myStr, 3, 4);

$final = $second . '-' . $first;
```

But I was looking for a simpler way rather than writing 5 full lines to do something simple. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex in [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do this work.

```
$final = preg_replace("/(\d+)-(\d+)/", "$2-$1", $myStr);
```

Check result in [demo](https://ideone.com/Mwcf1H)

Comment: I like this solution as if there were more than two pairs this could easily be tailored to accomodate extra pairs/positions..+1

Answer (score 3):

Is it shorter ? :)

```
echo implode('-',array_reverse(explode('-',$myStr)));
```

Comment: I had the same logic in mind :-) doing the 'ol switcheroo.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but I'll mark the other one as answered as it's more general. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
$myStr = "18-04";
$chuncks = explode("-",$myStr);
$final = $chuncks[1]. '-' . $chuncks[0];
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not reduced enough for my taste haha :P